# Subdivision Surface Modifier Mask?

Tags: modeling

Can I mask certain edges/vertices/faces from a subdivision surface modifier? I am working with small models and want to have some edges sharp yet others smoothed. Because of how think the object is and how I beveled it, it looks horrible when smoothed. I'd like it if I could somehow mask certain edges or faces from it, or to choose faces that should be sharper?

I have tried to add loop cuts and bevels, but with how badly I made the model, it wont work with the vertices. I will try moving them and seeing if they may be overlapping, or I messed up by making a complicated panel without extra edges. But loop cutting isn't working as it should.

I also tried adding creases but they didn't change anything about how the model looks with the modifier. I will show images of all that I tried. I want to have the sides sharp, but the inside smoothed out. I don't know if shade smooth renders, but it it does it still looks weird for what I am going for.

I also tried using an edge split modifier, but it didn't change anything either, like the previous answers. I did clean up the vertices, there aren't doubles. [image: All answers and effects.]

Comment: Hello :). You can add an edge crease amount to make some edges sharper.

Comment: @JachymMichal How do I add that? I am still learning a lot, since I've started learning only yesterday.

Comment: I've used this before, but it wont work with my model. I am making a very unusual shape that had many vertices and edges that mess with the modifier. I've tried doing this, but it doesn't help much. @JachymMichal

Comment: Hey :). You can edit your question, list all the solutions that didn't work for you and perhaps add an image of your mesh :). The linked thread contains 4 different solutions.

Comment: I don't save often because I am an idiot, and now the files are gone anyways. I'll still try to fix this for future models though. Just need to edit the images again. Is there an auto-save feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem you have is the topology. Avoid faces that have more than 4 vertices. Those will not work for what you want to do.

All of those examples don't work because of those n-gons.

Start with a shape like this:

[image]

You can create all kinds of "unusual shapes", but you have to have the topology in mind when creating them.

Then you will be able to appreciate the difference between all of the proposed ways to mix smooth and hard edges.